# XML Schema - restricting tag occurrences

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<Performance>
  <grouping usingTarget="M/R" />
  <state code="test"/>
  <state code="test2"/>
</Performance>
```

How do I write XML schema for the following so that only a single (required) `grouping` tag can be specified, however, unlimited (or zero) `state` tags can be specified?

Currently I have this which is allowing additional grouping tags.

```
  <xsi:complexType name="PerformanceType">
    <xsi:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsi:element ref="grouping" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"  />
      <xsi:element ref="client"  />
    </xsi:choice>
  </xsi:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:complexType name="PerformanceType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="grouping" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"  />
      <xs:element ref="state" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```